# bootstrap-table column-event adding a event object

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, object, bootstrap-table

Currently i am using `window.operateEvents` as `data-events` for one of my `bootstrap-table columns` Thing is i want to split this up in multiple files for permission perposes. Then only what needs to be loaded will be loaded.

This works now but i am combining two `objects properties`. `property` by `property`. Is this the fastest/best way?

Also is there a way to make this work without even combining the two `objects` that `bootstrap-table` will recognize thats better?

```
/**
 * Overwrites obj1's values with obj2's and adds obj2's if non existent in obj1
 * @param obj1
 * @param obj2
 * @returns newObj a new object based on obj1 and obj2
 */
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    // If object1 doesn't exist just give back obj2
    if(typeof(obj1) === "undefined" ){
        return obj2;
    }

    var newObj = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { newObj [attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { newObj [attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return newObj;
}


    /**
     * @brief operator events for actions on the rows
     * @type void
     */
    window.operateEvents = merge_options(window.operateEvents,{
        'click .edit': function(e,value,row,index){
            requestConfirm(e,value,row,"update", 
                function(){
                    $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh', "{silent: true}");
                }
            );
            e.stopPropagation();
        }                          
    });

    /** Add delete functionality */
    window.operateEvents = merge_options(window.operateEvents, {
         'click .remove': function(e,value,row,index){
            requestConfirm(e,value,row,"delete", 
                function(){
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh', "{silent: true}");
                }
            );
            e.stopPropagation();
        }       
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to start adding each action to your operateEvents object by property name.

For example:

```
window.operateEvents['click .edit'] = (function() {
//some edit stuff
});

window.operateEvents['click .remove'] = (function() {
//remove some stuff
});
```

Hope this helps.